# grunt - config object

Tags: json, gruntjs

This sample grunt file https://gruntjs.com/sample-gruntfile reads in a config object from `package.json` and stores it in the `pkg` property:

```
pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json')
```

However, the page doesn't give a sample `package.json` file. Later on it refers to `pkg.name`. I assume this is a top level key in `package.json`. E.g.

{
     "name": "this value here",
   }

Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's correct.

The `package.json` file is the heart of `npm` which is used by grunt.

You can generate one for your project using `npm init`and filling out the options or you can manually create and update it.

It gets updated automatically when using the `--save` option when adding modules to `grunt`.

```
npm install grunt-contrib-copy --save
```

This will install the module to your `node_modules` folder and update the dependencies section in your `package.json`

You only need to save the `package.json` file in your repo and each developer can download all dependencies listed in your `package.json` by calling `npm install`